# Typescript-Error when sending props. Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created an object of some type and I am trying to pass it to a component. But whenever I pass the props is saying that cannot read properties of undefined.(read 'stepOne').
The error is on the line value={data.stepOne?.TG_TE_number || null}

Here is the object:

```
export type DVTStepperType = {
    stepOne?: StepOneData
  };

  export type StepOneData = {
    id: number;
    number: number;
    project_title: string;
    DVT: Boolean;
    catalog: Boolean;
    start_date: Date | string;
    end_date: Date | string;
    TG_TE_number: number;
    budget: number;
    short_title: string;
    short_description: string;
    comment?: string;
    department: string;
    costs_ran_on: string;
    documentation: string[];
    report: string[];
    project_report_sending: string;
    status_id: number;
    client_location_id: number;
    overall_contact_person: string;
    representative: string;
    other_authorized_persons: string[];
  }
```

And here is the component I am trying to pass the props:

```
type Props = {
  data: DVTStepperType;
  updateData: (obj: DVTStepperType) => void;
  setPromptDisabled: (value: boolean) => void;
  services: [userService: UserServiceInterface];
};

const StepOne: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  data,
  updateData,
  setPromptDisabled,
  services: [userService],
const checkAllFieldsAreEmpty = () => {
    return (

      (
        !data.stepOne.start_date &&
        !data.stepOne.end_date &&
        !data.stepOne.department &&
        isEmpty(data.stepOne.overall_contact_person) &&
        isEmpty(data.stepOne.representative) &&
        !data.stepOne.budget &&
        !data.stepOne.TG_TE_number
      )
    );
  };

  function updateStepOneData<T extends keyof StepOneData>(value: StepOneData[T], name: T) {
    setPromptDisabled(checkAllFieldsAreEmpty());
    updateData({
      ...data,
      stepOne: {
        ...data.stepOne,
        [name]: value
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <Grid container justifyContent='space-between'>
      <Grid sx={classes.input}>
        <ServiceDescriptionHeader />
      </Grid>
      {isLoading ? 
        (<SkeletonLoader /> 
        ): (
        <>
      <Grid item xs={5.9}>
        <TextField
          sx={classes.input}
          type='text'
          variant='standard'
          value={data.stepOne?.TG_TE_number || null}
          onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            const newValue = +e.target.value;
            if (newValue >= 0) {
              updateStepOneData(newValue, "TG_TE_number");
            }
          }}
          label={t('TG/TE-Number')}
          helperText={`${data.stepOne.TG_TE_number} / ${128}`}
          inputProps={{ readOnly: isReadOnly, maxLength: 128 }}
          required
        />
```

As i said it doesnt see the 'stepOne' but I have the object declared.

Comment: On what line is the error?

Comment: value={data.stepOne?.TG_TE_number || null}

Comment: the code calling `StepOne` is not passing a value for data.  e.g. look where you do `<StepOne data={something that is undefined} />`.  That is where your problem is

Answer (score 1):

The data prop was possibly passed undefined from the parent component.
You can fix it like this.

```
value={data?.stepOne?.TG_TE_number || null}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I have a question. I followed this example here: https://pastebin.com/MJpukmHE
and in this example is working fine